# ASP.net MVC level based approval application. Do I need to use workflow?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui, workflow-foundation-4

I am developing an application which is based on approval process. Basically an employee working on-site will create a request. That request needs to go through various levels to get final approval.

**High level process:** On-site employee -> Supervisor ->  Level II Manager -> Control Manager -> Assign for Delivery

**Sample Scenario:** On-site employee requested for cell phone with data plan and wanted it by 3/1/2014

He/She will create a request by filling out a MVC form where they will *choose* their supervisor or alternative person, Level II manager.

Upon submitting the request, the MVC application need to start a process/workflow and should send out **automatic alerts via email** to next level. Also the MVC application need to fire reminder emails if requested date nearing or waiting in queue at a particular level.

I want to do this (reminders, etc) without human interaction. Is it possible using MVC and Workflow? Any thoughts?

Comment: Any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the use case for a BPM, .NET have a small piece of software that wraps up the windows workflow foundation with BPM capabilities on top of that

the site is [bpm4net](http://www.bpm4net.com/) take a look it may be doing your life a little bit easier!

> The BPM.NET Designer is a standalone tool from the BPM.NET "The
>   designer also provides features such as Execution, Tracking, and
>   External Assembly Referencing etc."

You can host it IIS

> "As BPM.NET strictly follows the standard of Windows Workflow, it can
>   be seemlessly designed and hosted in IIS and Appfabric."

this is an [old video](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-1/aspnet-mvc-storefront/aspnet-mvc-mvc-storefront-part-19-processing-orders-with-windows-workflow) of how you could integrate Workflow and MVC, it needs to be updated but it can give you the path to follow in terms of **integration**.

and take s look to another interesting [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42072/Flexible-Web-UI-Workflow-application-through-ASP-N) to manage workflows and mvc